# WooCommerce - Add email to MailChimp list based on product/s attribute value?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, mailchimp

To preface, I know there is a WooCommerce MailChimp Plugin for Wordpress but from what I understand all it does is assign any user who makes a purchase to a single list.

What I'm trying to do is store a MailChimp list id inside as a custom product attribute to which a user would get assigned upon purchasing said product.

I know I can use MailChimp's API to add email address to lists I am just unsure where I need to add this functionality into WooCommerce?

Comment: Have you asked support if the plugin handles list segmentation by product? I don't actually know myself.

Comment: They say they'll be adding it in an upcoming Pro (paid) version of their plugin. I've got the functionality I want working but it's in the active theme's functions.php file. I feel like that isn't the best place for it in case the theme is changed. I guess I need to know how I'd build a custom plugin to integrate with woocommerce.

Comment: You are correct that functionality should be stored in the theme's functions.php. There are lots of tutorials out there on how to build a plugin, but here's a [plugin boilerplate generator](http://wppb.me/) that could get you started.